# Docker log file: How to know the time of notes?

Tags: logging, time, docker, server

I have server's log file from docker container.
How could I know when the exact row had been written?

The log views like:

```
...
[90mGET /api/clients [32m200 [90m31ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients/564adbadf9e6a9cf7281053f/getAllClientsByAdmin [32m200 [90m19ms[0m
[90mPOST /api/clients/50000b00000389/heartBeat [32m200 [90m38ms - 210b[0m
[90mGET /api/clients [36m304 [90m17ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients [36m304 [90m19ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients/56a752ad53259fa20629da24/getAllClientsByAdmin [36m304 [90m26ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clientFiles/download/7aa4f7d3e4a5ecaebd86696f642c9204 [33m404 [90m4ms - 9b[0m
[90mGET /api/clients [36m304 [90m14ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients/4edd40c86762e0fb12000003/getAllClientsByAdmin [36m304 [90m19ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients/5644a32ce9e9a5125be6adc1/getAllClientsByAdmin [32m200 [90m88ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients [32m200 [90m80ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients/5644a32ce9e9a5125be6adc1/getAllClientsByAdmin [32m200 [90m49ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients [36m304 [90m35ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients [32m200 [90m40ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients/564adbadf9e6a9cf7281053f/getAllClientsByAdmin [32m200 [90m39ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients/564adbadf9e6a9cf7281053f/getAllClientsByAdmin [36m304 [90m44ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients/5644a32ce9e9a5125be6adc1/getAllClientsByAdmin [32m200 [90m58ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients/564adbadf9e6a9cf7281053f/getAllClientsByAdmin [36m304 [90m105ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients [32m200 [90m136ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients [32m200 [90m112ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients [36m304 [90m74ms[0m
[90mGET /api/clients/564adbadf9e6a9cf7281053f/getAllClientsByAdmin [36m304 [90m70ms[0m
[90mHEAD /api/systemUpdates/19000b000008b5/getUpdate?version=3 [36m304 [90m7ms[0m
[90mHEAD /api/systemUpdates/11000b00000919/getUpdate?version=3.1 [36m304 [90m6ms[0m
...
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/):

```
Usage: docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER

  ...

  -t, --timestamps          Show timestamps
```

Example:

```
docker logs -t mycontainer
```